# How to delete a row from a file csv?

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a code to delete a line from a file and for some reason the deletion deletes all the content from the file and I can not figure out what is wrong with my code ...
If there is anything that can help me?
Thank you!
lines = list()

```
members = int(rownumber)

with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\plan.csv', 'r') as readFile:

    reader = csv.reader(readFile)

    for row in reader:

        lines.append(row)

        for field in row:

            if field == members:
                lines.remove(row)

with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\plan.csv', 'w') as writeFile:

    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)

    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: It'd help you to single step through the program run in a debugger. That will show you what the program is actually doing and you can compare it to expectations. PyCharm has an excellent debugger.

Comment: Or simple print statements like `print(f"writing {len(lines)} lines")`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify the condition for excluding a line from the file.
I am going to assume you want to remove line number `members`

```
members = int(rownumber)

with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\plan.csv', 'r') as readFile:

    reader = csv.reader(readFile)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        # 'i' holds to current row number
        # if it's equal to 'members', don't append it to the list
        if i != members:
            lines.append(row)


with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\plan.csv', 'w') as writeFile:

    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)

    writer.writerows(lines)
```